# How to fetch the object from the array in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-4

How can I fetch the object from the array; I'm getting this data from the query.

I query this table:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM verified_data where target_id=3");
```

and getting this result:

```
array(124) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#445 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(83)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["target_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["target_type"]=>
    string(6) "assets"
    ["user_comments"]=>
    string(13) "Well and good"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-11 18:35:39"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-11 18:35:39"
    ["is_verified"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#446 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(84)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["target_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["target_type"]=>
    string(6) "assets"
    ["user_comments"]=>
    string(13) "Well and good"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-11 18:48:07"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-11 18:48:07"
    ["is_verified"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#447 (8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(85)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["target_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["target_type"]=>
    string(6) "assets"
    ["user_comments"]=>
    string(13) "Well and good"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-11 18:48:26"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-11 18:48:26"
    ["is_verified"]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

And I want the `["is_verified"]` from the this data, how can I get this in a variable and then display it in my `input` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all records and get `is_verified` field:

```
$data = DB::table('verified_data')->where('target_id', 3)->get('is_verified');
```

or:

```
$data = DB::table('verified_data')->select('is_verified')->get();
```

For a single row use:

```
$data = DB::table('verified_data')->where('target_id', 3)->first('is_verified');
```

or:

```
$data = DB::table('verified_data')->select('is_verified')->first();
```

More information in [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects).

I hope, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM verified_data where target_id=3");

if ( !empty($data) && is_array($data) ) {
    foreach ( $data as $record ) {
        $record->is_verified; //TODO do something with this value
    }
}
```

Comment: i just want the value which is stored in `[is_verified] ` which should be 1 or 0 so how can i get this value and stored in variable??